# tr:commandlink color specified in css is not working,while the same is working in inline style

Tags: css, jsf, myfaces

```
<tr:commandLink inlineStyle="color:green" value="mylink" />
```

shows "mylink" in green , while the below line of code doesnt change color of link

```
<tr:commandLink styleClass="myStyle" value="mylink" />
```

and css is below

```
<style>
.myStyle
{color:green;}

</style>
```

when i try to change the color of the link by using style class it is not changing. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like trinidad skin is overriding your color. To prevent this, you need to set `!important` in your style.

```
<style>
.myStyle {color:green !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<h:commandLink>
  <h:outputText value="myLink" styleClass="myStyle" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: but i need disabled property also to be present which i get it from tr:commandlink,but it is not present in the h:commandlink

Comment: Would you be able to use the rendered property instead?

Comment: my requirement says to even disable it ,render will not show the link itself in the screen